# What's the difference of personal statement for funding and for admission?

Tags: funding, statement-of-purpose

I am applying for a Ph.D. position in the UK. However,after I submitted my admission application, I found that the funding application requires another personal statement. What's the difference? Could I just submit the same one? Or I could write one based on my admission personal statement?

Comment: What do the instructions say for each statement?

Comment: The admission one said a lot. Like you should write your motivation, your experience, your research plan, why this university. But requirements for the funding one is just 500 words.